# Redis on azure debian vm - connect ETIMEDOUT

Tags: debian, azure, redis

I made a Debian 9 VM on Azure, I also installed MariaDB, PHPMyAdmin, and node with pm2. With this, I set in inbound rules port 80 for HTTP, 3306 for MySQL and port 6379 for the Redis.

when i try to connect with the windows client it refuses or in code it also refuses and i get "Error: Redis connection to [someIP]:6379 failed - connect ETIMEDOUT [someIP]:6379". when I change the connection settings to another Redis I own it does work, so there shouldn't be an issue with the code.

in short: what should I check for a successful connection from my home network to the Redis on Azure.

Comment: `redis-cli`, the default host is `localhost`. If you want to access redis from Internet, the service could not listen on localhost, you should use private ip. Then use `redis-cli -h <private ip>` and `redis-cli -h <public ip>`. Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi, does it work for you? Please let me know if you need more future help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I refer this [official document](https://www.hugeserver.com/kb/install-redis-4-debian-9-stretch/) and install redis on Debian 9. I could connect it with VM Public IP.

You should enable Redis is listening on VM's private IP. By default, it listens on localhost. Modify `/etc/redis/6379.conf` as below:

```
bind <vm's private ip>
```

Then restart Redis. `systemctl restart redis_6379`.

Check connection on Linux.

```
root@shui:~/redis-stable/utils# redis-cli -h 52.232.114.152
52.232.114.152:6379> set test HugeServer
OK
52.232.114.152:6379> get test
"HugeServer"
```

Note: You should open port 6379 on NSG like this [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aghk5.jpg).

Comment: I also test on Windows client, it also works for me. https://imgur.com/a/aEz2m

Comment: I suppose you mean redis.conf?

Comment: Yes, maybe it is a mistake, I will check it.

Comment: What is the result `netstat -ant|grep 6379`?

Comment: @AchielVolckaert I test in my lab, this is `/etc/redis/6379.conf `. Do you find it in your VM?

Comment: yes, after a reinstall i found it, now reconfiguring everything

Comment: @AchielVolckaert You need listen redis on VM's private IP. Also, open port 6379 on Azure NSG and VM's firwall(I test in my lab, no need).

Comment: this is the result of netstat https://imgur.com/a/TCgaN 10.0.0.4 is my private ip. command redis-cli says it can't connect.https://imgur.com/a/cWuxB

Comment: i added the rule in nsg, i even set the redis config to accept all ip's, i have no clue

Comment: Hi, you should use `redis-cli -h 10.0.0.4` or `redis-cli -h <publicip>`

Comment: Redis is not listen on 127.0.0.1.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71567/discussion-between-shengbao-shui-msft-and-achiel-volckaert).